# Unable to Edit a deployed C# project in VS from AOT

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, aot

In my test system when I edit a C# project via the AOT in AX 2012 (R2 CU6) it should open the project in Visual Studio, however it shows the project as unavailable in VS.

[image: Visual Studio Solution Explorer showing project unavailable]

I can see the AOT object in the Application Explorer in Visual Studio (2010), I can edit and deploy reports and can debug classes in VS - so the link to the AOT is there and working.

I have tried removing and reinstalling the VS AX tools via AX Component Setup.

I was getting 'The specified client configuration does not contain valid WCF settings' error - but fixed this (as no longer getting the error) using [Justin Carter's excellent blog on the subject](http://daxdude.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/error-specified-client-configuration.html)

Comment: Did you try to run AX as administrator?

Comment: Do you mean as a domain administrator? As my user already is.

Comment: Ok, but did you run the AX client application as administrator (right click, run as administrator)?

Comment: @FH-Inway - tried that and no difference

Comment: Are you in the correct layer? (`CUS` vs `USR`)?  If you're in a test system, you're likely in the `USR` layer and if the project is in the `CUS` layer, that might be an issue. What do you mean "unavailable"?

Comment: Yes i'm in the USR layer - the project in VS has (unavailable) next to it in solution explorer

Comment: @AlexKwitny how do I change to the CUS layer and why can't I access it in the USR layer?

Comment: @PeterCampbell - You need to have the layer access key, then you follow these directions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa673975.aspx

Comment: @AlexKwitny where does the layer access key come from?

Comment: You have to get it from your partner or lcs. It sounds like you shouldn't be doing this development.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111776/discussion-between-peter-campbell-and-alex-kwitny).